# Is There a Way to Discard Empty Captures?

Tags: c++, regex, string, iterator, spinach

Is there a built in way to iterate over non-empty captures only or do I need to use a lambda/modify my regex?

For example, given: `const auto input = "Peas&Carrots Spinach-Casserole Beets Pizza Spinach-Salad Coleslaw"s` I'd like to find foods that *don't* contain "Spinach". So I can do this:

```
const regex re{ "\\s*(?:\\S*Spinach\\S*|(\\S*))" };

copy(sregex_token_iterator(cbegin(input), cend(input), re, 1), sregex_token_iterator(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
```

The problem of course is that [I get an output](http://ideone.com/Gdt4hC) like:

> Peas&Carrots
>   
>   Beets
>   Pizza
>   
>   Coleslaw

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::copy_if` and a lambda to check that the string from the regex match is empty or not.  Using

```
copy_if(sregex_token_iterator(cbegin(input), cend(input), re, 1), 
        sregex_token_iterator(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"), 
        [](const std::string& match){ return !match.empty(); });
```

We get

```
Peas&Carrots
Beets
Pizza
Coleslaw
```

<sup>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f1a6b1e3a660975)</sup>

As it will only print non-empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way would be to use `std::copy_if` (or `std::remove_copy_if`) and copy the string only if it's non-empty.

```
remove_copy_if(
    sregex_token_iterator(cbegin(input), cend(input), re, 1),  
    sregex_token_iterator(), 
    ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"),
    [](string const &s) { return s.empty(); } 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the answers of those wiser than I, it seems that there is in fact no way to discard empty results without a lambda. In this question there are a couple alternatives though:

1. Use a Look Ahead, which is a bit more expensive, but only captures words without "Spinach":

```
const regex re{ "(?:\\s+|^)(?!Spinach)(\\S+)" };

copy(sregex_token_iterator(cbegin(input), cend(input), re, 1), sregex_token_iterator(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/yJkw2Q)

2. Use an `istream_iterator` and a lambda, this removes a lot of the flexibility of the lambda, but since `input` is white-space delimited this is probably the best option:

```
istringstream{ input };

copy_if(istream_iterator<string>(cbegin(input), cend(input)), istream_iterator<string>(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"), [](const auto& i) { return i.find("Spinach") == string::npos; });
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/hBWRHn)